# Should the Client call the Server or should the Sever call the Client? What do I miss?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, client, html5-canvas

How do I merge/connect my two working code parts? (I use `HTML5-Canvas`, `Javascript`, `C#`, `ASP.NET`).

1)
I can write some shapes to my `HTML5 Canvas`, from some hardcoded values. I do this from a `Javascript` function onto my `HTML5-Canvas` (This part works). But I want to give this `JavaScript` function an array to work with. (I need this. Can this function call the `Server` so it get returened the arrray? Or should this `Javascript` function be called from `C#(Server)`).

2)
I have an `ASP.NET Button`, that can trigger a `C#` method that can return the needed array.

I'm missing a "link" here, so the arrray is "carryed" over to the `Javascript` function.

Is this possible? 
Is it up to the `C#` funktion to call the `Javascript`? Or is it the other way around, so from my `Javascript` function i ask for the array from the `C#` somehow?

This Client/Server part is confusing. I don't know any *best practices* here.

```
The same explained again in a more speakable way:
```

I'm rewriting my ASP.NET website that have an four-on-a-row game, and 7 buttons for each of the columns. The button trigger an C# method that do something and the used an .ashx handler to return a bitmap i used in C# to set an Image on the html.
Now I'm trying to use HTML5 and the canvas instead. I have the C# method that knows how the board should look like.
Recently I just made some Shapes on a HTML5-Canvas from Javascript. I just don't know how I can put these two working things together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript(client) calls the C#(server). You can use AJAX.

Return the array from C# to JavaScript using JSON. Then you use JavaScript to draw your shapes in HTML5 Canvas

Comment: Okay, how I don't know JSON yet? :)

Comment: JSON is very simple. Find a tutorial where a C# method returns JSON from a JavaScript AJAX call.

Comment: With these hobby project, I'm trying to learn my self, HTML5/CSS3 and Javascript, so it's a little hard to comprehent that I have to learn JSON now before i can get back to the three other language. I rather close one before open another, do you know what I mean? But he you say so. I will edit some code soon.

Comment: JSON is just a way to serialise objects. You will get the hang of it. :)